# Eclipse Android Package Refactoring Fails - Internal Error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest, adt, automated-refactoring

I am trying to use the Android Tools > Rename Application Package option in Eclipse to test my changes to FBReaderJ on my tablet while keeping the official version available. When I use this command and enter a new name, I get an error:

```
An unexpected exception occurred while creating a change object. See the error log for more details.
```

In the error log, I have:

```
Internal Error
```

Stack Trace:

```
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$13.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:1675)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:1672)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.createChange(RefactoringWizard.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.computeUserInputSuccessorPage(RefactoringWizard.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizard.getStartingPage(RefactoringWizard.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showStartingPage(WizardDialog.java:1271)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createContents(WizardDialog.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1089)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation$1.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.run(RefactoringWizardOpenOperation.java:122)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.refactorings.renamepackage.RenamePackageAction.initiateAndroidPackageRefactoring(RenamePackageAction.java:168)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.refactorings.renamepackage.RenamePackageAction.promptNewName(RenamePackageAction.java:151)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.refactorings.renamepackage.RenamePackageAction.run(RenamePackageAction.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3554)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3179)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.refactorings.renamepackage.ApplicationPackageNameRefactoring$JavaFileVisitor.visit(ApplicationPackageNameRefactoring.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource$2.visit(Resource.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource$1.visitElement(Resource.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.doIteration(ElementTreeIterator.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTreeIterator.iterate(ElementTreeIterator.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.accept(Resource.java:108)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.refactorings.renamepackage.ApplicationPackageNameRefactoring.createChange(ApplicationPackageNameRefactoring.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CreateChangeOperation.run(CreateChangeOperation.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

Session Data:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800
java.version=1.6.0_24
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
```

I am very new to Android and I don't know where to begin here. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465127/rename-android-package-name-fails) seems to be a very similar issue, but I cannot figure out what [user756905](https://stackoverflow.com/users/756905/user756905) was suggesting should be tried...

Any suggestions are welcome, especially if there is anything I can try before I try reinstalling Eclipse.

Comment: I ended up using a search and replace which worked. I would still like to understand why the 'Rename Application Package' function does not work for this repo.

Comment: I just had this issue too, with regular Java, not Android...

Comment: Since this post the repo has updated and I am now able to use the android refactoring feature.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that for some of your classes it could not fined package to rename.
Try a search in the project to check if you have somewhere class without package or if it is commented.